# Transform 2 lists into a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists:

```
keys = ['p', 'e']
vals = [['p1', 'p2', 'p3'], ['e1', 'e2', 'e3']]
```

How do iterate over them to create a list of dicts like this:

```
result = [{'p':'p1', 'e':'e1'}, {'p':'p2', 'e':'e2'}, {'p':'p3', 'e':'e3'}]
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
keys = ['p', 'e']
vals = [['p1', 'p2', 'p3'], ['e1', 'e2', 'e3']]

list_of_dicts = [ { keys[0]: val1, keys[1]: val2} for val1, val2 in zip(vals[0], vals[1]) ]
print(list_of_dicts)
```

**EDIT:**
In the general case:

```py
keys = ['p', 'e', 'z']
vals = [['p1', 'p2', 'p3'], ['e1', 'e2', 'e3'], ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']]

list_of_dicts = []
# spread vals array
for values in zip(*vals):
    temp_dict = {}
    for key, val in zip(keys, values):
        temp_dict[key] = val
    list_of_dicts.append(temp_dict)
print(list_of_dicts)
```

Prints:

```
[{'p': 'p1', 'e': 'e1', 'z': 'z1'}, {'p': 'p2', 'e': 'e2', 'z': 'z2'}, {'p': 'p3', 'e': 'e3', 
'z': 'z3'}]
```

Comment: yes, it works for my case when i only have 2 keys and 2 lists in vals, but if I have one more key and one more list in vals, it does not work anymore.